# Access the root TreeNode in router v.3-alpha.8

Tags: javascript, angular

With the first router v.3 versions, I was doing that somewhere in my code :

```
let lastColors: Colors;
let node = this.router.routerState._root;

do {
    if(node.value.component.hasOwnProperty('__colors')) {
        lastColors = (<any>node.value.component).__colors;
    }
} while(node = node.children[0]);
```

However, the `_root: TreeNode<ActivatedRoute>` property of `RouterState` is now private in alpha 8, breaking my code. It seems that now, RouterState isn't exposing the root TreeNode anymore. What's the proper way to explore the components tree now?

Comment: There is no `private` in JavaScript at the end of day

Comment: It's TypeScript, I should have precised that, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in fact that was simple, I didn't read the router's .d.ts files with enough attention:

```
let lastColors: Colors;

let state = this.router.routerState.snapshot;
let route = state.root;

do {
    // do something with route.component
} while(route = state.children(route)[0]);
```

**Update:** @angular/router is now stable and the API changed, again. Here is the new version :

```
let state = this.router.routerState.snapshot;
let route = state.root;

do {
   // do something with route.component
} while(route = route.children[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `this.router.routerState.root`

```
export class RouterState extends Tree<ActivatedRoute> {
  /**
   * @internal
   */
  constructor(
      root: TreeNode<ActivatedRoute>, public queryParams: Observable<Params>,
      public fragment: Observable<string>, public snapshot: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    super(root);
  }

  toString(): string { return this.snapshot.toString(); }
}
```

Comment: That's not the same thing, `routerState.root` is the root `ActivatedRoute`, I'm searching for the root `TreeNode<ActivatedRoute>`, which is very useful, but seems to be only used internally and not exposed.